# Guest vs host system speed

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

Can the guest system running in the vm be faster than the host system (the same system, windows xp proffesional for example)?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see how. Even of the guest has direct access to the hardware, it has at most the same (normally less) processing time and at most the same (normally less) RAM available as the host.

Comment: If it WERE possible, then you could just run a VM inside a VM inside a VM to get an infinitely fast system!

Comment: What if the guest system is cleaner (fresh installation) and therefore more efficient?

Comment: It would still be running ontop the "junked up" Operating System